# MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED and PACKAGE_REPLACED actions don't start on the real device, but on the emulator - ok

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'm testing getting broadcast events on updating my app.

```
<receiver android:name=".UpdNotifyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

```
class UpdNotifyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        Log.d("info", "0 - from receiver")

        if ( intent.action == Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED ) {
            Log.d("info", "1 - from ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED")
        }

        if ( intent.action == Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED ) {
            Log.d("info", "2 - from ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED")
        }
    }
}
```

It's working ONLY on the emulator in Android Studio, but on a real device - does not work.
Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: What devices have you tested it on?

Comment: @DavidWasser I tested it on Xiaomi

Comment: Those devices often have special restrictions for apps getting broadcast `Intent`s while they aren't running. Sometimes you need to add your app to a list of "protected apps" or "apps allowed to run in the background" or something like that. I would suggest you try this on other devices and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks for your answer. Can I programmatically turn on "apps allowed to run in the background"?

Comment: No, you cannot. You can only ask your user to manually add your app to this list.